# Play Store app won't automatically update with error: APP_IN_FOREGROUND

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app in the Play Store that won't automatically update on newer devices. The update shows as available, and can be manually installed by clicking on it, but it just sits there (for weeks) when automatic updates are on, it is plugged in, and idle.

This doesn't make sense to me since it requests to go into the foreground, but then even if the app isn't the one open to the user, and even if it stays that way for a week, it still won't update.

Seemingly relevant logcat text:

```
Skipping install. reason=APP_IN_FOREGROUND
```

The logcat shows that it won't install because it is in the foreground, but it seems like this should eventually install anyway. What can i do to allow this to install? Is there a notification I can receive and exit the foreground? Or a setting to allow it to update even when it is in the foreground?

Full logcat entries:

```
I Finsky  : [387] muv.b(40): IQ: Notifying installation update. package=com.example, status=DOWNLOAD_PENDING
I Finsky  : [2] mvc.a(2): IQ: Requesting install request=package_name=com.example, version=xxx, priority=3, reason=auto_update, account_name=[], type=0, constraints=((REQ_CHARGING, REQ_DEVICE_IDLE, REQ_GEARHEAD_PROJECTION_OFF, NETWORK=UNMETERED, PROVISIONING_STATE=PROVISIONED),)
I Finsky  : [2] mjw.a(109): Installer: Request install. package=com.example, version=xxx, mods=null, priority=3, reason=auto_update
I Finsky  : [2] mjw.a(68): Installer: Notifying status update. package=com.example, status=DOWNLOAD_PENDING
I Finsky  : [2] mjw.a(159): Installer: kick starting installation. package=com.example
I Finsky  : [2] mjw.a(225): Installer: found apps to install. isMultiUserMode=false, apps=[com.example]
I Finsky  : [2] mjw.a(248): Installer: skip com.example, the app is in foreground
I Finsky  : [2] mjw.a(254): Installer: Skipping install. package=com.example. reason=APP_IN_FOREGROUND
I Finsky  : [2] mjw.a(68): Installer: Notifying status update. package=com.example, status=INSTALL_ERROR
```

Also, this seems to happen only on Android 8.1 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates the app has some services that run in foreground, could be a bug. Manually updating the app is logical because it kills the process, while background updating wouldn't work. Try posting the app, or some of the code. I think the problem is with your code, that the app is running in foreground all time.

Answer (score -1):

According to what the logcat says the app is still in the foreground and according to my understanding you need to clear it off from the ram and recently used apps (maybe even give a sweet little restart to your phone) and then try again.

Comment: This isn't about my device. This is about auto updating across all users devices. Those that have auto updating enabled should be able to update eventually, even if the app is in the foreground initially. What that mechanism is (from the app's perspective, not the user's) is the point of this question.